# How to change the tip text of getFieldDecorator dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, antd

In the example component `NormalLoginForm` from the official website here https://ant.design/components/form/, for the username item,

```
<FormItem>
  {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
  })(
      <Input addonBefore={<Icon type="user" />} placeholder="Username" />
    )}
</FormItem>
```

If the server returns an error caused by wrong password, how to  show and change the message from `Please input your username!` to `Wrong username or password` ?

## antd

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example: https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-register

You can use customized validate method, and you can validate async, too.

Comment: Please incorporate the linked material here. Any external links are subject to change, and can adversely effect your answers quality in the future.

Answer (score 0):

the message in the rules can be a variable
I would do it like below

```
<FormItem>
  {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
    rules: [{ required: true, message: (errorFromServer || 'Please input your username!') }],
  })(
      <Input addonBefore={<Icon type="user" />} placeholder="Username" />
    )}
</FormItem>
```